# How to find a non-recursive formula for a recursively defined sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

Given:

$\mu(0)=0$

$\mu(i)= 2\mu(i-1) + 2^{i-1} \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall i \in N $

I would like to know if there is any way of obtaining the non recursive formula for $\mu (i)$:

$\mu(i) =  i2^{i-1}$

That doesn't rely on figuring it out by looking the patterns and then proving it by induction.

Comment: Well, if you define $a_n=\frac {\mu_{n}}{2^{n-1}}$ then you can confirm that $a_0=0$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}+1$ which clearly implies $a_n=n$.  Good enough?

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear enough in my question, but you were not supposed to prove the validity of the non-recursive formula but to deduce it from it's recursive definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(n)z^n$ be the ordinary generating function.  The recurrence relation implies that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) z^n = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n-1)z^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n-1} z^n,$$
equivalently,
$$f(z) - \mu(0)z^0 = 2 z f(z) + z \cdot\frac{1}{1-2z}.$$
Solving for $f(z)$ yields
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(1-2z)^2},$$
whose partial fraction decomposition
$$f(z)=\frac{-1/2}{1-2z}+\frac{1/2}{(1-2z)^2}=\frac{-1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2z)^n+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{1}(2z)^n$$
immediately implies that
$$\mu(n)=\frac{-1}{2}2^n+\frac{1}{2}\binom{n+1}{1}2^n=-2^{n-1}+(n+1)2^{n-1}=n2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear enough in my question, but you were not supposed to prove the validity of the non-recursive formula but to deduce it from it's recursive definition.

Comment: I did deduce it.  The generating function approach I showed leads to the desired explicit formula without knowing what it is ahead of time.

Comment: Oh, sorry I'm not understanding some steps, why it's  okay for you to do u(n) = 2 u(n-1) at the start?

Comment: I multiplied both sides of the recurrence relation $\mu(n)=2\mu(n-1)+2^{n-1}$ by $z^n$ and summed from $n=1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: ok I understood that! now the other doubt is how do you assure that |2z|<1 so that the geometric series converges?

Comment: Generating functions are formal power series and do not require convergence.

Comment: Looks like I'll need to learn how generating functions works to fully understand your answer (as I don't know what is the partial fraction decomposition  and how it implies the final result). Anyways thank you for your answer and explanations.

Comment: [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Examples_of_generating_functions_for_simple_sequences) is a good place to start.  Wilf's *generatingfunctionology* and Chapter 7 of *Concrete Mathematics* are also quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

Define $$a_n=\frac {\mu_n}{2^{n-1}}$$

Then, $$a_0=0\quad \&\quad 
a_n=\frac {2\mu_{n-1}+2^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}=\frac {\mu_{n-1}}{2^{n-2}}+1=a_{n-1}+1$$

which implies that $a_n=n$, and we are done.

Comment: Very nice! How did you came up with that?

Comment: It seemed natural to try to kill off the $2^{n-1}$ term and this was the first thing I tried that felt like it would have that effect.